# Swtor: If I play the class story but then skip KOTFE, will my class choices reset?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So I have played KOTFE several times now and playing it again with my inquisitor just to get past it is kind of boring. So If I skip to KOTET, will the choices I made in my class story reset? E.g Will I lose my Ashara Romance etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only the intermediate KotFE choices will be made for you to "catch you up".  See http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=9061741&postcount=14